# Filling height in Angular material form

Tags: css, material-design, angular-material

I've got a form in Angular Material (Cordova app) which has three inputs: title, log type and description. And then there's two buttons to save and cancel. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
<md-content layout="column">

<div layout="row" layout-padding>
    <md-input-container layout-fill>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.newLog.Title" class="md-display-1" />
    </md-input-container>
</div>

<div layout="row" layout-padding>
    <md-input-container layout-fill>
        <label>LogType</label>
        <md-select ng-model="vm.newLog.LogType">
            <md-option ng-repeat="logType in vm.logTypes" value="logType.value">
                {{logType.display}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</div>

<div layout="row" layout-padding flex="noshrink" height="auto">
    <md-input-container layout-fill>
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea ng-model="vm.newLog.Description" />
    </md-input-container>
</div>

<div layout="row" layout-padding layout-align="end center">
    <md-button ng-click="vm.cancelNew()" class="md-raised md-primary">CANCEL</md-button>
    <md-button ng-click="vm.saveNew()" class="md-raised md-primary">SAVE</md-button>
</div>
```

I want the "Description" field to be multi-line and fill up the available screen real estate (height). It doesn't do that. Also, the Layout field is rendered differently than I expected. Below the screenshow of how it looks, looking for the proper way to do such a layout.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/OXxAkm)

Markup

```
<div id="all" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content layout="column" layout-fill layout-padding>
    <!-- Title -->
    <md-input-container flex="none">
      <label>Title</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="vm.newLog.Title" class="md-display-1" />
    </md-input-container>

    <!-- Log Type -->
    <md-input-container flex="none">
      <label>LogType</label>
      <md-select ng-model="vm.newLog.LogType">
        <md-option ng-repeat="logType in logTypes" value="logType">
          {{logType}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

    <!-- Description -->
    <div id="description" layout="column" flex>
      <md-input-container flex>
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea ng-model="newLog.Description"></textarea>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <div layout="row" layout-align="end center" flex="none">
      <md-button ng-click="vm.cancelNew()" class="md-raised md-primary">CANCEL</md-button>
      <md-button ng-click="vm.saveNew()" class="md-raised md-primary">SAVE</md-button>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#all {
  height: 100%;
}

#description {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The things to note are:

- The parent of the `md-content` should have full height so that the `layout-fill` fills the whole height
- The `input` and buttons `div` should have `flex="none"` so that they don't scale up
- The `textarea` has a parent `div` with `flex` (equivalent to `flex="100`) so that it scales up, `layout="column` and `overflow-y: auto` (so that over flowing text is scrollable)
- The `textarea` has `flex` so that it fills its parent

Comment: Added ng-cloak on the Description <div> to remove the additional padding it added to the lay-out. Apart from that, perfect answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Jasper Glad to be of help. I think a better way to go is to remove `layout-padding` as it adds padding to all children and replace it with just CSS padding. That means you wouldn't have to add `ng-cloak` to the div for example. Also, thinking about it, I'm not sure those `flex="none"` are really required.